# Does regex validation work when input type="number"?

Tags: javascript, regex, html, browser, input

When using **`type="number"`** on an input field, **regex** validation does not appear to work.

```
<input type="number" step="any" min="0" max="24" value="0">
```

The new broswer based validation using **`step, min, max`** works as expected. However this is not consistent accross browsers?

http://jsfiddle.net/EkL3k/1/

---

**QUESTION**

How to make a number field validate using regular expression?

*I'm also interested in other factors that differentiate a number and text field if anyone has information.*

**NOTES**

I have discovered that checking for an empty string causes validation to fire **IF** the conditions on the number field are not met.

Comment: You can always call your validation by script on keyup. Or just set remove the type=number and do it with regex only.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Key up makes no difference and I need type number for device keypads.

Comment: You can use `element.validity.valid` to check if the input contains valid number. There is also a `pattern` attribute in which you can set a regex to validate your input. Finally, you can prevent a user from typing something else than numbers by using keypress : http://stackoverflow.com/a/15649226/2806497

Comment: BTW, be cautious with those new inputs, they're not fully implemented in all browsers (for example, firefox added support for it in its last update). I would not recommend to use it in a production context.

Comment: Exactly which is why I am using regular expression validators to ensure full support. I cannot rely on the number validation built into the browser.

Comment: I wasn't specifically talking about validation, I just meant those new inputs could lead you to face issues in existing javascript, on older browsers or even with styling. Personally, I won't use them for the moment, even if they are great new features.

Comment: Noted. thanks Oliver. fortunately for my project I have the option to say update or lose out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A number field performs its own validation, if it contains a non-numerical character, the value will automatically be removed until a correct value is given. You can see this with a `console.log(value)`.

So you could also check for an empty string

```
function check(value, msg) {
  var valid = ((value != '') && /^\d*\.?\d*$/.test(value));    
  if (valid) {
      document.getElementById(msg).style.display = "none";
  } else {
      document.getElementById(msg).style.display= "inline";
  }
  return valid;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EkL3k/6/

Comment: This is true however not all browser behave, validation wont be consistent and regular expressioon validators prevent data submission which I also require.

Comment: Checking empty string does cause validation to occur if value is outside number field specified quantities.

Answer (score 1):

RegEx does not work because the returned value is a *number*, not a *string*. It works 'as expected' when you force the returned value to string format:

```
var valid = /^\d*\.?\d*$/.test(String(value));
```

You might want to read [How to get the raw value an <input type="number"> field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852244/how-to-get-the-raw-value-an-input-type-number-field) as it suggests you don't *have* to validate a `type=number` input.

Comment: This is true however not all browser behave, validation wont be consistent and regular expressioon validators prevent data submission which I also require.

Comment: Well it worked for me after changing just this line in your fiddle. ..?

Answer (score 0):

add this code and add an id to your input.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#txtboxToFilter").keydown(function (e) {
    // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter and .
    if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190]) !== -1 ||
         // Allow: Ctrl+A
        (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) || 
         // Allow: home, end, left, right
        (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
             // let it happen, don't do anything
             return;
    }
    // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
    if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IDEGu