# How to allow only 4 digit numbers in html textbox?

Tags: html, regex

I have tried to restrict users in HTML text box to insert only 4 digit numbers 0-9.

I have tried as follows but it restrict only to allow two digit numbers.

```
<input type="text"  name="pincode" maxlength="4"  id="pin" pattern="^0[1-9]|[1-9]\d$" required/>
```

Comment: Try `pattern="\d{4}"`. No need to use anchors since the pattern attribute is anchored by default.

Comment: Maybe `type="number" maxlength="4"` :-?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález It doesn't prevent user from entering non-digit characters. Also, `maxlength` will only restrict from entering more than 4 characters. So, entering 0,1,2,3 characters is valid. Here OP want to restrict user to enter **exactly 4 digits**.

Comment: @Tushar That's right, you only get a validation error. But AFAIK that's all you can get with plain HTML.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Let me clarify:  any of the `^[0-9]{4}$` or `^\d{4}$` are valid regexps to restrict values to 4 digits only. However, [`pattern` HTML5 attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-pattern-attribute) value is already anchored by default:

> The regular expression language used for this attribute is the same as that used in JavaScript, except that the **pattern attribute is matched against the entire value**, not just any subset (somewhat **as if it implied a `^(?:` at the start of the pattern and a `)$` at the end**).

So, use just `pattern="\d{4}"`:

```css
input:valid {
  color: green;
}
input:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<form name="form1"> 
 <input type="text"  name="pincode" maxlength="4"  id="pin" pattern="\d{4}" required/>
 <input type="Submit"/> 
</form>
```

BTW, your `^0[1-9]|[1-9]\d$` pattern matches only 2 digit inputs because it matches either `0` followed by any digit from `1` to `9`, or any digit from `1` to `9` followed by any digit.

**Also, note that `pattern="\d{4}"` attribute does not prevent entering non-digit symbols into the field**. See [How to prevent invalid characters from being typed into input fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282266/how-to-prevent-invalid-characters-from-being-typed-into-input-fields) post how to solve that.

Comment: Its not working for input : type="number". How to set for it??

Comment: @MukhlisRaza There are other SO threads devoted to that, see [Does regex validation work when input type=“number”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23673982/3832970) for example.

Answer (score 14):

Please try adding the following:

```
<input type="text" 
       maxlength="7" 
       onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'    
       required 
/>
```

Comment: This is the best answer.

Comment: Agreed. Why reinvent the wheel with regex stuff?

Comment: add  || charCode <= 89 &&  charCode >= 80 for numpad numbers

Answer (score 6):

Change your regex like so:

```
pattern="\d{4}"
# allows numbers from 0000-9999

pattern="[1-9][0-9]{3}"
# from 1000-9999
```

A pattern like `{1,4}` would allow numbers with 1 up to 4 digits, a pattern like `{x}` fixes the number of digits to x times.

**Edit:** As @Tushar pointed out, the formerly regex `[1-9]{4}` was wrong as it did not allow any zeros.

Comment: As Stribizhev explained in his answer, when using `pattern` attribute you don't need anchors. Also, the second regex `^[1-9]{4}$` does not match numbers `1111-9999`. It matches numbers from 1111 to 9999 **not containing any zero**

Comment: That's wrong again. `1[0-9]{3}` will match `1000-1999`. You're looking for `[1-9][0-9]{3}`.

Comment: If you want to read, start with [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/). To test regex online use [regex101](https://regex101.com/).

Answer (score 5):

Change your pattern like below,

```
pattern = "^[0-9]{4}$"
```

Repeatation quantifier `{4}` should repeat the previous token exactly `4` times.

Answer (score 0):

```
pattern="\d{4}"
```

allows numbers from 0000-9999

```
pattern="[1-9][0-9]{3}"
```

allows numbers from 1000-9999

A pattern like `{1,4}` would allow numbers with 1 up to 4 digits. A pattern like `{x}` fixes the number of digits to `x` times.