# Backspace doesn't work in Firefox Angular 2

Tags: angular, firefox, backspace

I have an **input field** (type text) and I have to avoid to introduce there any character no numeric in there. Also, the field is limited to 4 numbers (is a year field).
When I got it, the field don't allow to use the backspace or delete key from the keyboard.

I tried several solutions from this page but none of them work for me.

**I think the problem is related with the limitation of the field for only number**, because if I remove this option the keys *backspace* and *delete* works fine!

**The .html is:**

```
<tab heading="{{'Ressources du Foyer' | uppercase}}" [disabled]="!isEdit || !isODP">
                <table [defaultElemPerPage]="999" [data]="dataRessources" [config]="configRessources" [columns]="columnsRessources"
                    [showElementsPerPageSet]="false" [showItemNumberInfo]="false" [doHover]="false" [doClick]="false" [showActionsHeader]="!modeConsultation">
                    <template let-data>
                        <p class="text-center" *ngIf=!modeConsultation>
                            <a (click)="addRowLineRessources(data.index)" class="purple-icon" *ngIf="data.last" title="Ajouter une ligne"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>
                            <a (click)="removeRowLineRessources(data.index)" title="Supprimer une ligne"><span class="purple-icon glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a>
                        </p>
                    </template>
                </table>
            </tab>
```

**The file .ts:**

```
anneeReference: this.createStandardComponentService.createInputText({
        id: 'anneeReference',
        type: 'text',
        disabled: false,
        group: group.get('anneeReference'),
        errors: this.errors.anneeReference,
        outputMethod: this.validYear,
        maxlength: 4
      }),

validYear(event: any) {
    const pattern = Constants.NUMBERS_PATTERN;
    const codeCle = event.keyCode;
    const inputChar = String.fromCharCode(event.charCode);
    if (!pattern.test(inputChar) && (codeCle !== Constants.BACKSPACE_TOUCHE || codeCle !== Constants.DELETE_TOUCHE)) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
```

I expected to have a field with max 4 characters, only numbers, where I can erase any change in any moment.

Comment: Maybe you should tink refactoring your solution. Read more https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34556035/how-to-allow-only-4-digit-numbers-in-html-textbox/34556265

Comment: Thanks for answer @NicolaeOlariu. If you see the code, we don't use the table than the HTML code. This solution doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this error **by another solution**, removing the filter that forbids us *add any character non numeric* (before accepted by the client, 'cause it's a modification of the specifications given).

Be that as it may, could be another solution into the **[Mozilla Forum](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/984262).**