# How to get a number value from an input field?

Tags: javascript, html, input-field

I have some issues with calculating some stuff with JS and getting the right values out of the input fields (number). When I use this code it doesn't show anything. So what is wrong with my JS? Do I need to include a jQuery file?

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
        <form  id="frm1" action="Calculate.html">
            <table width="350px" border="1px">
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2">Availability</th>
                </tr>       
                <tr>
                    <td>Total Production Time</td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="TotalProductionTime" placeholder=""> hours</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Breaks</td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="Breaks" placeholder=""> minutes</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Malfunctions</td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="Malfunctions" placeholder=""> minutes</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Theoretical production time:</td>
                    <td><p id="test"></p></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

<input type="button" onclick="Calculate()" name="Calculate" value="calculate">
<script>
    function Calculate()
    {
        var TotalProductionTime = document.getElementById("TotalProductionTime").value;
        var TotalProductionTimeInMinutes = TotalProductionTime * 60;
        var Breaks = document.getElementById("Breaks").value;
        var Malfunctions = document.getElementById("Malfunctions").value;
        var TheoreticalProductionTime = TotalProductionTimeInMinutes - Breaks - Malfunctions;       

        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = TheoreticalProductionTime;
    }
</script>   

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `.value`  returns a string. Use `parseInt(x, 10)` or `parseFloat`.

Comment: you are using `getElementById` and you haven't any ID set.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get value of <input type="number"> with JS when it contains non-numeric characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15627341/get-value-of-input-type-number-with-js-when-it-contains-non-numeric-characte)

Comment: You can also use `.valueAsNumber` to get a number instead of a string.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You had some mistakes in your HTML, but here is a working JSFiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chs9x9wj/)

You you are trying to get elements by their ID, but you don't give them an ID you give them a Name. Also, stop using inline JavaScript calls; it is bad practice.

```js
function Calculate() {
    var TotalProductionTime = document.getElementById("TotalProductionTime").value;
    var TotalProductionTimeInMinutes = TotalProductionTime * 60;
    var Breaks = document.getElementById("Breaks").value;
    var Malfunctions = document.getElementById("Malfunctions").value;
    var TheoreticalProductionTime = TotalProductionTimeInMinutes - Breaks - Malfunctions;

    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = TheoreticalProductionTime;
}
```

```html
<form id="frm1" action="Calculate.html">
    <table width="350px" border="1px">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Availability</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Total Production Time</td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" id="TotalProductionTime" placeholder="">hours</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Breaks</td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" id="Breaks" placeholder="">minutes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Malfunctions</td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" id="Malfunctions" placeholder="">minutes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Theoretical production time:</td>
            <td>
                <p id="test"></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="button" onclick="Calculate()" value="calculate">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, what did you change? :x aahhwww nvm I see it now.. No ID's set just as Yerko Palma mentioned. My god :x

Comment: The `name` of the button has to differ from the `onclick` function or in your case I would leave it (`name`) out. Also if you want the elements by ID, give them an ID and not a name.

Answer (score 16):

Every id must be converted to integer. Example

```
var Malfunctions = parseInt(document.getElementById("Malfunctions").value);
```

then your ready to go

Comment: This is the best answer, for avoiding a concatenate instead of addition

Comment: Please use `parseInt` [_with_ the second parameter, `10`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16880327/4642212). Consider using [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#Function_syntax) or [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) instead, or, specifically for `<input>`s, [`.valueAsNumber`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#Properties).

Answer (score 15):

With [`HTMLInputElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) you can use property `.valueAsNumber` which returns a numeric property if possible:

```js
const str = document.querySelector("input").value;
const num = document.querySelector("input").valueAsNumber;

console.log(typeof str, str, str + 2);
console.log(typeof num, num, num + 2);
```

```html
<input type="number" value="40" disabled />
```

Answer (score 2):

You've got two problems here. One obvious is that you try to get a reference to the form inputs by `id`, but didn't give them any (you gave them a `name`). To fix, either change the `name` attribute to an `id`, or use the form-specific way to reference them, e.g.:

```
var TotalProductionTime = document.forms.frm1.TotalProductionTime
```

Second problem is more vicious and has to do with the scope of execution of what you put in `onclick` attributes. You see, your button is named "Calculate" just like your function, and in the context of the `onclick` attribute, its parent form is used to resolve identifiers before the global scope. So instead of calling the function named Calculate, you're trying to call the button itself. Fix that by giving them different names, referencing `window.Calculate` explicitly, or much better, define your event handler in JavaScript instead of using the HTML attribute:

```
document.forms.frm1.Calculate.onclick=Calculate
```